# Como integrar um código Java com um em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsf

```java
//retorna o usuário logado no sistema
public class ContextObject {

    public static Usuario getUsuario() {
        ContextObject contextObject = ContextFactory.getContextObject();
        return contextObject.usuario;
    }    

}
```

```html
//mostra em uma função alert() o usuário logado
<script> alert(ContextObject.getUsuario()); </script>
```

Tendo em vista que esses dois códigos estão em arquivos diferentes.

Estou fazendo isso mas não está certo, como devo fazer? Preciso pegar o retorno do código java e mostrar o que esta chegando na função `alert` do javascript.

Comment: Se o código javascript for executado do lado do cliente e o código java estiver do lado do servidor, parece-me uma tarefa difícil de executar. Nesse caso AJAX poderá ser uma solução para esse problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inicialmente você deveria ter um método que retornasse um json com os dados desejados, pode ser na mesma classe.

Mas envolveria uma configuração REST que não citarei aqui, mas pode encontrar neste [link](http://www.k19.com.br/artigos/criando-um-webservice-restful-em-java/) e [aqui](http://www.k19.com.br/artigos/webservice-restful-utilizando-json/).

O método você anota seu método com `@GET` e `@Produces("application/json")` e a classe com a anotação `@Path("/caminho")`.
Também deverá anotar sua classe usuário com `@XmlRootElement`.

No seu javascript você pode chamar o método via GET do HTTP.
Algo assim:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("/caminho", function(data) {
        alert(data.nome);
    });
});
```

Comment: data seria o nome da classe?

Comment: cria a rest pra min? nunca fiz nada do tipo :(

Comment: Não, data é o argumento que estou passando para o método. Usei data pois significa dados em português. É meio que um padrão, mas pode ser o nome da classe se desejar. Sobre o REST postei dois links que ensinam a fazer, é só seguir o tutorial.